# The formula for conditional expectation in terms of joint cdf

Tags: joint-distribution, conditional-expectation, cumulative-distribution-function

We know that covariance can be written as a function of marginals and joint CDFs, namely
$$\newcommand{\cov}{\operatorname{cov}}\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}\cov(X,Y) = \iint (F_{X,Y}(x,y) - F_X(x)F_Y(y))\,\d x\,\d y$$
How can we rewrite $E(Y|X<a)$ in the same way as function of CDFs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P[Y<y|X<a]=\frac{F_{X,Y}(a,y)}{F_X(a)}$$
So,
$$E[Y|X<a]=\int{1-\frac{F_{X,Y}(a,y)}{F_X(a)}dy}=\int{\frac{F_X(a)-F_{X,Y}(a,y)}{F_X(a)}dy}$$

Comment: We are assuming that $Y$ has positive support here, right?

Comment: Yes, in the first step.

Comment: In the first step, the conditional distribution of Y given X<a needs to have positive support. If the distribution of Y given X<a has support that is bounded below by -M where M is a positive number, then it can still work with some easy modification since Y+M now has positive support and $E[Y|X<a]=-M+E[Y+M|X<a]$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the requirement "Y | X < a needs to have positive support"?  What does it mean?  Can you provide example and counterexamples of applying the formula where this coition holds / does not hold?  Thank you

Comment: @Confounded It means not possible for Y to be less than or equal to 0;  that is $P[Y>0|X<a]=1$.